# Query questions based on 'last_activity_date'

Tags: support, api

Is there a way to query questions based on 'last_activity_date' in StackExchange API? 
The API documentation says that 'fromdate' parameter considers the creation_date for the query.

My use case is that I want to get all the questions in which 'last_activity_date' got changed since a particular timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API doesn't explicitly list it as a parameter, you can't filter on it.

But in this case, you can *sort* on it (in descending order), fetch the first page, and process the results. If all questions pass the filter, fetch the next page and repeat; if there's a question which was last active *before* your cut-off date, you can stop processing.